# "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:0: Connection refused''"

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code:

```
$this->connection = new MongoClient($uri, $options);
$this->database = $database;
```

However, at line `$this->connection` I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:0: Connection refused' in...
```

If I output the following:

```
var_dump($uri, $options); exit;
```

I get:

```
string(33) "mongodb:///tmp/mongodb-27017.sock" array(1) { ["connect"]=> bool(true) }
```

This is in my dev environment, I'm not using any username/password for Mongo as I can login to the Mongo shell with `mongo reputation` alone. From there I can view collection and documents.

Originally I was getting Permissions denied, but I changed the permissions of my dev /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock to 777. Now I get "connection refused".

Anyway below is the file from my `ll /tmp/` dir:

```
srwxrwxrwx  1 mongodb mongodb     0 Jan 28 07:47 mongodb-27017.sock=
```

Anyone know what the issue is, or how I can debug further? Thanks

Comment: What is the permissions and ownership of your /tmp directory?

Comment: Hi. The tmp dir is `drwxrwxrwt   7 root root 20480 Jan 28 08:17 tmp/`

Comment: Does it work if you leave off the `$options` and just use `$this->connection = new MongoClient($uri);` ?

Comment: Also, when you restart mongo, the permissions you've changed will be reverted back to 700 when it recreates the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend in PHP connecting not to the socket which your process might not have permissions to access.  If you modify the permission of the socket it's only temporary.  When you stop the mongo db it will delete the socket, the next time you start it, the permissions will be back to whatever the default is (700 I think).

Instead connect to the to the default port (27017) mongo opens on 127.0.0.1.

Change you connection string in PHP to the following:

```
$uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1";
$this->connection = new MongoClient($uri, $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection=  new \MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
return $this->db = $connection->selectDB($config['dbname']);
```

try this to connect local mongoDB.